# SSIS Package: Dynamic Connection with XML Result

Tags: xml, dynamic, ssis

> I want to create SSIS package for unit test to run automatically.
>   I have some queries which I want to run daily bases on different servers and need to store 
>   result in central database.the problem is i want the result in XML.
>   I can connect different servers dynamically and store result in central database but this 
>   time I have a result in XML and getting problem.
>   **Sample script**

```
Use AdventureWorks2008
Go
Create Schema UT
Go
CREATE TABLE [UT].[MasterTask](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UTName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [SelectFromServer] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SelectFromDatabase] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SelectStatement] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [UT].[SelectResult](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MasterTaskID] [int] NULL,
    [Result] [xml] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL
)

Select * From UT.MasterTask
Insert Into UT.MasterTask Values
('Testing','Local','AdventureWorks2008','SELECT Name, ProductNumber, ListPrice AS Price
FROM Production.Product 
WHERE ProductLine = ''R'' 
AND DaysToManufacture < 4
ORDER BY Name ASC;',GETDATE(),GETDATE())
Insert Into UT.MasterTask Values
('Testing','Server1','AdventureWorks2008','SELECT  TOP 100 P.ProductID, 
 P.Name, 
 P.ListPrice, 
 P.Size, 
 P.ModifiedDate, 
 SOD.UnitPrice, 
 SOD.UnitPriceDiscount,
 SOD.OrderQty,
 SOD.LineTotal 
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD 
INNER JOIN Production.Product P 
 ON SOD.ProductID = P.ProductID 
WHERE SOD.UnitPrice > 1000 
ORDER BY SOD.UnitPrice DESC',GETDATE(),GETDATE())
Insert Into UT.MasterTask Values
('Testing','Server2','AdventureWorks2008','Select * From Person.BusinessEntity',GETDATE(),GETDATE())
```

> Here is three database servers Server,Server1 and Server2,every time I will create a dynamic > source connection from UT.MasterTask(SelectFromServer and SelectFromDatabase Column) table > > and execute task that defined in SelectStatement column of UT.MasterTask table and insert 
>   XML result in UT.SelectResult table. 
>   Note:
>   The result column is not fixed.
>   Need single xml entry for each row. 
>   Execute query that defined in SelectStatement of UT.MasterTask